# Is it possible to create a branch from a tag in TortoiseSVN without first checking out the tag from SVN server?

Tags: tortoisesvn, tags, branch

Our trunk directory contains about 100mb of code and we create tags from the trunk directory.  Normally, this is not an issue because a tag takes up no space until you need to use it for something.  Since branches are created from tags in SVN, how can I create a branch from a tag wtihout first checking out the tag?  It appears I need to do a Tortoise Update from Windows Explorer to get the tag down to my local machine before I can use Tortoise > Branch/Tag... to create a branch from it.  This seems illogical since we don't make changes to tag folders, and it requires that I check out 100mb of code, only to create a branch, and then check out another 100mb of code in the branch folder, where the changes will actually be made.

Ideally, I'd be able to create a branch directly in the repository via RepoBrowser - but I can't see an option for it there.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 18):

Creating a branch is just a matter of copying the desired directory to another location.  This can be done directly in the Repo Browser.

There is nothing special that differentiates a branch from a tag as far as Subversion is concerned.  It is just a convention to store them under separate parent folders, named 'branches' and 'tags' accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the info - just so I'm clear, you are saying I can continue to create tags like I normally do.  To create a branch, I can go into Repo Browser and right-click the tag folder and select Copy To..., and specify new folder under branches?  That makes a lot more sense and keeps everything a shadow copy on the server until I'm ready to check out the branch to my local machine to do some work.

Comment: Yeah exactly.  You don't need to only create branches from tags though.  Many people will create a branch by copying the current trunk.  Depends on your workflow...

Comment: The menu option "Copy To..." in this case is poorly named, even more misleading when  you use it as the dialog text is "Rename 'http://(your-tag-URL)...': New name:

Answer (score 12):

The only difference between tags and branches is your attitude towards them -- they are equivalent behind the scenes -- shadow copies made in the repository.

You don't even need a working copy to create a branch/tag.  For example, you can use this command-line:

```
svn copy http://server/test/trunk http://server/test/branch -m "make branch"
```

(assumes you have SVN.EXE in addition to TortoiseSVN, otherwise, use Ben's answer)